# Unable to test controller using MockMVC

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mockmvc

I am trying to test my controller using MockMvc. While performing this mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn(); It doesn't hit my API. So I am getting this response.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The Mock Response object should be same 

 Expected :dGVzdDEyMw==

 Actual   :
```

This is my controller class

```
public class AddLibClientRestController
{

@Autowired
private AddAPIService addAPIService;


  @PostMapping(value = "/v1/add")
public String encrypt (@RequestParam final String plainText) throws GeneralSecurityException
{
    return addAPIService.add(plainText);
}

}
```

This is my test class

```
public class AddLibClientRestControllerTest
{


/** The instance of EncryptionAPIService. */
@MockBean
private AddAPIService mockAddAPIService;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;


  @Test
  public void testEncryptWithMockObjectReturned () throws Exception
{
    final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder =
        post("/v1/add")
        .param("plainText", "test123");
    when(mockAddAPIService.add(anyString())).thenReturn("dGVzdDEyMw==");
    final MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
    assertEquals("The Mock Response object should be same", "dGVzdDEyMw==",
        result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
}

}
```

Please suggest something, what i am doing wrong here in this. Thanks

Comment: try to print out the response (`.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())`) to see what the result is. I guess you get a return code != 200

Comment: @Jens MVCResult doesn't have any method with such name .andDo. I am trying this way result.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());

Comment: try `mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print()).andReturn()`

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use the provided `andExpect` matchers, such as `andExpect(status().isCreated())` (or similar); if you're getting a 500 instead, the MockMvc infrastructure will print useful debugging information. These days, it's also generally helpful to return a JSON object even for a single value, and in that case you can easily use the `jsonPath` matcher.

Comment: I am getting status as 404. As it is not able to find and hit API /v1/add ????

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I am getting status as 404. As it is not able to find and hit API /v1/add ????

Comment: That's exactly why to use the built-in assertions: Now you know the problem is a mapping problem, and can debug it. (Hint: Set logging for `org.springframework.web: DEBUG` and you will see a list of all of the mappings that Spring sets up.)